Spie(s) sent out to scout Yazer
In Parshat Chukat (21:32), we are told that Moshe Rabbenu sent out spie(s) to scout the land of Yazer.
Are there any sources that identify who went to scout out the land of Yazer?

While the primary midrashim on this pasuk don't seem to identify them by name, the תרגום המיוחס ליונתן on this pasuk identifies them as Kalev and Pinchas:

וְשָׁדַר משֶׁה יַת כָּלֵב וְיַת פִּנְחָס לְאַלָלָא יַת מַכְבַּר
וּכְבָשׁוּ כּוּפְרָנָהָא וְשֵׁיצוּן יַת אֱמוֹרָאֵי דְתַמָן

Incidentally, the Targum Yonason translates יעזר here as "מכבר" and the other two times it appears in the Chumash (later in במדבר) it's translated as the similar "מכוור". For more on equating יעזר with מכוור see this Jastrow entry and this article and a related Wikipedia article. Also see the Mishna in Tamid 3:8 which says:

אָמַר רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר בֶּן דִּגְלַאי, עִזִּים הָיוּ לְבֵית אַבָּא
בְּהַר מִכְוָר

It's also an interesting parallel that the Midrash Tanchuma (in addition to במדבר רבה וילקוט שמעוני) even identifies the spies sent out at the beginning of Sefer Yehoshua as Pinchas and Kalev:

וְאֵין לְךָ בְּנֵי אָדָם שֶׁנִּשְׁתַּלְּחוּ לַעֲשׂוֹת מִצְוָה
וְנוֹתְנִין נַפְשָׁם לְהַצְלִיחַ בִּשְׁלִיחוּתָן, כְּאוֹתָן שְׁנֵי
שְׁלוּחִים שֶׁשָּׁלַח יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בִּן נוּן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וַיִּשְׁלַח
יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בִּן נוּן וְגוֹ' (יהושע ב, א). וּמִי הָיוּ. שָׁנוּ
רַבּוֹתֵינוּ, אֵלּוּ פִּנְחָס וְכָלֵב, וְהָלְכוּ וְנָתְנוּ נַפְשָׁם
וְהִצְלִיחוּ בִּשְׁלִיחוּתָם.

